# PTR doesn't match hostname on SMTP HELO command. What to do?

Tags: smtp

I'm struggling with an issue regarding hosts connecting to my SMTP server.

For instance, one client is connecting to my SMTP server with the given hostname : `EUR02-AM5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com`.

Unfortunately, the IP doesn't match that hostname (52.101.131.25).

Based on the SMTP rules, I should refuse this email, but when I do a reverse IP lookup for 52.101.131.25, I get `mail-bgr052101131025.outbound.protection.outlook.com`, which **also comes from Outlook.com** !

So, even if the hostname doesn't match the IP, the IP is originating from a valid source in that case (outbound.protection.outlook.com).

Unfortunately I can't go up between the two hostnames to find a common operator, because at some point, I could validate ".com" agains't ".com".

And Outlook is not the only one doing so, here's the case with Zoho:

`HELO sender21-mail.zoho.eu` coming from the IP `185.20.209.254`.
But when you do a reverse lookup, you don't find `sender21-mail.zoho.eu`, but ... `sender.zoho.eu`

How can I do to ensure that both hostname come from the same valid source, that's just the IP that is badly configured?

Thanks!